# FirebaseAuth: The method 'getCredential' isn't defined for the type 'EmailAuthProvider'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

i have the following Problem:

[image]

[image]

I'm new in Firebase and i don't know, how can i fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

API changed, so you could try with:

```
credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

They have changed a bit methods` names. You should write EmailAuthProvider.credentials now

Comment: Also see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#authentication